# How to fix legend overlap when combining Stata graphs?

Tags: graphics, legend, stata, catplot

I have the following graphs done using this code:

```
legend(rows(3) size(small) bmargin(zero) rowgap(0) colgap(0) label (2 "Charcoal") label(3 "Rudimentary wood planks") label(4 "Animal dung") label(1 "Others")) ///
blabel(bar, format(%9.0f) color(white)  size(vsmall) position(inside)) bargap(5) graphregion(color(white))  ytitle("Percentage %") ///
ylabel(, nogrid) b1title("") l1title("") title("Cooking fuel")
graph save "11", replace

catplot floor1 [aw=${weight}], recast(bar) percent asyvars stack ///
legend(rows(2) label(2 "Sand/Earth") label(3 "Dung") label(1 "Others") size(small) bmargin(zero) rowgap(0) colgap(0)) ///
blabel(bar, format(%9.0f) color(white)  size(vsmall) position(inside)) bargap(5) graphregion(color(white))  ytitle("Percentage %") ///
ylabel(, nogrid) b1title("") l1title("") title("Floor")
graph save "22", replace

catplot watersource [aw=${weight}], recast(bar) percent asyvars stack ///
legend(rows(2) size(small) bmargin(zero) rowgap(0) colgap(0) label(1 "Other") label(2 "Public tap") label(3 "Tubewell/Borehole") label(4 "River/stream/lake")) ///
blabel(bar, format(%9.0f) color(white)  size(vsmall) position(inside)) bargap(5) graphregion(color(white))  ytitle("Percentage %") ///
ylabel(, nogrid) b1title("") l1title("") title("Water source")
graph save "33", replace

catplot toilet [aw=${weight}], recast(bar) percent asyvars stack ///
legend(rows(3) size(small)) legend(label(1 "Other") label(2 "Pit latrine with slab") label(3 "Pit latrine without slab/open") label(4 "No facilities/in the bush")) ///
blabel(bar, format(%9.0f) color(white)  size(vsmall) position(inside)) bargap(5)  ytitle("Percentage %") ///
ylabel(, nogrid) b1title("") l1title("") title("Sanitation")
graph save "44", replace

graph combine "11" "22" "33" "44", iscale(0.8)
```

This is the output. The legend is overlapping the graph area and doesn't look great. Any idea on how to stop that without making the legend size/font even smaller?

Thanks!!

[image: mdp]

Comment: I'd back up and try something quite different and I have ideas on what might work much better. I have to suggest that you would be better off on Statalist where there could be a conversation rather than an open-ended question (with no reproducible data-based example for anyone to work on) that is hard to answer.

Comment: You intended, I imagine, including an extra line of code at the top.

Comment: True, the first line is missing, it's similar to the other ones. I can't share the data, as this is for work/a private dataset, but can try to replicate it with a generic dataset.

Comment: You've already shared the results graphically.  You could show the results of `tab1` with your four variables (applying the weights). Sorry, but each forum has its own style and the kind of answer I could give with discussion of different kinds of graphs really doesn't match expected style on SO.  In a nutshell, my view is that stacked bar charts don't work well in general and they don't work well for your data, and that your main problem is trying to squeeze a lot into the space available; squeezing harder is not the answer. All just one opinion....

Comment: Apart from giving examples of `catplot` (which can be found elsewhere) I can't see any advantage here to future readers or any progress possible here if you're reluctant to post data (understandably). or even summaries.

Comment: I'd suggest using four bar graphs or histograms, perhaps using `catplot`, with the current legend labels as axis labels.